# Is it possible to forward a request changing the request method?

Tags: java, rest, servlets

I'm working thorough a gateway, which allows only GET requests, whilst REST endpoints behind it are able to accept the wide range of methods (POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS). Therefore, I'm trying to pass the request method as a parameter, having a filter, which forwards the request with a correct method. From what I can see in the specification, it's only allowed to forward the request w/o any modifications:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(route).forward(request, response)
```

Are there any workarounds?

NOTE: Redirect is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single Rest servlet that handles the restful services (and this is usually the case), you can extend it and override the `service` method. There you can invoke `doPost(..)`, `doPut(..)`, etc. depending on the parameter you want. The default implementation of `HttpServlet` uses `request.getMethod()`.

Another thing you can do (less preferable) is to have your Filter fire a new request to the endpoint, using `URL.openConnection` (or apache commons http components), and stream the result of that internal request back to the client. There you can specify the request method.

Anyway, I think you should try to overcome the limitation of your gateway, because it puts you in a really awkward situation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom HttpServletRequestWrapper to override getMethod()

```java
public class ChangeHttpMethodFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    public class ChangeHttpMethodHttpServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
        public ChangeHttpMethodHttpServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
            super(request);
        }

        @Override
        public String getMethod() {
            HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.resolve(this.getRequest().getParameter("method"));
            return method == null ? super.getMethod() : method.name();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletRequest changeHttpMethodRequest = new ChangeHttpMethodHttpServletRequestWrapper(request);
        chain.doFilter(changeHttpMethodRequest, response);
    }
}
```