# Resteasy delegate route to another route

Tags: java, resteasy

I was wondering if there was a way to delegate to another route in RestEasy.

I.e., something along the lines of, begin in a method inside an RS:

```
@Path("/api")
public class Foo {

    @POST
    @Path("/foo")
    public Response foo() {
        return RestEasy.delegate("GET", "/api/bar");
    }

}
```

Where delegate would return the exact same response as if I had made an HTTP `GET` request to `api/bar`, that is, will fall through the proper RS that handles that route, ideally refilling all the necessary request information (headers, params, payload).

I don't want an HTTP redirect as I want it to be transparent to the api user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see from the docs/source that ***org.jboss.resteasy.spi.HttpRequest*** interface you have access to has a forward method.

It takes a string which would be the path to your other endpoint, but it doesn't let you change the method type (post to a get). But then again neither does the RequestDispatcher forward method you have access to. You aren't allowed to modify the request or the response.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545021/is-it-possible-to-forward-a-request-changing-the-request-method):

So really all you can do is directly call your service method or, use an HTTP client to call other REST endpoint inside ***foo*** and then stream that back to the client.